# Passing pointer to const ref function

Tags: c++

Why does the following work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PolyLine {
public:
  PolyLine() = default;
  PolyLine(PolyLine * ptr) {
    std::cout << "Ctor called" << std::endl;
  }

};

void function(const PolyLine& pt) {
}

int main() {

    PolyLine *pobj = new PolyLine();

    function(   pobj );

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the implicit conversion is somehow getting called.. why aren't I getting a compile error?

Comment: `why aren't I getting a compile error` Why do you expect an error?

Comment: You have defined an implicit conversion, and the compiler uses that conversion. No surprise here.

Comment: You are missing `delete pobj;` at the end of main. Either fix it or thange the definition of pobj to this: `PolyLine pobj;`

Comment: @MarianSpanik this is a toy code, thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works because your implicit conversion constructor is being called, because that's what can happen when you pass something as an argument and you have a non-explicit constructor taking a single argument.

If you don't want implicit conversions to occur in this instance, you can mark the constructor as `explicit`:

```
explicit PolyLine(PolyLine * ptr) {
    std::cout << "Ctor called" << std::endl;
}
```

That said, it seems a bit odd to have a constructor taking a pointer to another object of the same class; why not use a `const PolyLine&`?

Comment: Because I'm a n00b, here's why. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you wanted to add `explicit` to the code snippet there? :)

Comment: For learning's sake: why is a reference better than a pointer in the constructor? To avoid it being null?

Comment: @Dean With a reference, the constructor is called a *copy constructor*, which allows you to pass objects by value, create as many copies as you want, etc. If you don't declare one yourself, one will be automatically generated (under certain conditions). See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way implicit conversion works in C++. If you pass a `char*` to a function which accepts a `std::string` as first parameter, C++ will convert the `char*` to `std::string` using the `std::string` constructor.

Answer (score -3):

If you will do any operation in `function (..)` that changes state of object then you'll get compiler error. Like following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PolyLine {
public:
  PolyLine() = default;
  PolyLine(PolyLine * ptr) {
    std::cout << "Ctor called" << std::endl;
  }

  void test ()
  {
    _a = 100;
  }

  private:
    int _a;
};

void function(const PolyLine& pt) {
  pt.test ();
}

int main() {

    PolyLine *pobj = new PolyLine();

    function(   *pobj );

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation output:

```
wbzz@mambet:/tmp$ g++ -std=c++11 main.c 
main.c: In function ‘void function(const PolyLine&)’:
main.c:21:12: error: passing ‘const PolyLine’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void PolyLine::test()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   pt.test ();
            ^
```

Comment: That's to do with the parameter being `const`, nothing to do with implicit conversions.